# Repeated letters during reading pdf arabic text by pdfbox

Tags: pdfbox

How can i avoid repeated characters during read Arabic PDF text using pdfbox?
this example this is a word:
بهم
when we read this word we get this result
بهرم
many thanks

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question?

Comment: @mkl Can you please send me your mail to send you the pdf file?

Comment: It would be preferable if you could share publicly (e.g. via a public google drive or dropbox share). This would allow others to check, too. E.g. a major contributor to PDFBox reads and writes on stackoverflow. That been said, you can find an address in my profile.

Comment: Sorry Mr mkl because i don't know how to share via a public google drive or dropbox share, this is link for pdf file:
http://www.4shared.com/office/m2Xks8u4ba/13_online.html

Comment: The problem is there are specific letter(one letter) repeated randomly when i read pdf i don't why?

Comment: I don't find a way to download from that site, at least not without having to register, and I am not going to register somewhere just to retrieve a file to inspect.

Comment: ok send me your mail

Comment: Sorry,I can not find your mail in your profile please send it to me.

Comment: I already send the file to mkl@wir-sind-cool.org thanks for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63100/discussion-between-ayman-and-mkl).

Comment: Ok, I received it. I'll take a look.

Comment: I tried to extract the text. As I neither know any Arabic nor have RTL-aware tools at my hand, analysis is quite difficult. At first glance, though, I could not spot the repetitions you talk about. Thus, please pinpoint exactly where on the page the repetition occurs (e.g. using a marked screenshot) and also supply your pivotal text extraction code.

Comment: Thanks for your help mr mkl and apologize me,I will simplify you the problem so that you can inspect it easily,
the first word in the first line in the pdf file from the left has 3 letters, this word become 4 letters in the output(there are additional letter in the word!), please check if this word exist in the pdf stream with 3 letters or 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make analysis of the issue easier, the OP provided a sample file and in a comment pointed towards a word illustrating the issue:

> the first word in the first line in the pdf file from the left has 3 letters, this word become 4 letters in the output(there are additional letter in the word!), please check if this word exist in the pdf stream with 3 letters or 4?

The first line of the PDF displayed in Adobe Reader looks like this:

[image: First line of PDF as shown in Adobe Reader]

The first line of the text extracted by PDFBox with sorting activated is

> طعم الرضرا والسرعادة، ويحيرا حيراة طيبرة مرع غيرره، فيسرعد بهرم

which in Total Commander looks like this:

[image: first line of text extracted by PDFBox]

The first line copied & pasted from Adobe Reader results in

> طعم الرضرا والسرعادة، ويحيرا حيراة طيبرة مرع غيرره، فيسرعد بهرم

Thus, it looks like PDFBox and Adobe Reader agree on the contained text, at least in my eyes which have no experience with Arabic writing. As Adobe Reader generally is quite good at text extraction, this is a hint that PDFBox extracts the text as the PDF claims it to be.

Looking at the innards of the PDF we find the operation outputting the left-most part of the line (glyphs are rendered left-to-right here):

```
[<000303E10467>-2<03EC03910003>-3<03A903CC>3<0467>-2<03B3>3<03F3>-3<03D3>] TJ
```

Thus, the left-most glyphs are represented by these codes:

```
0003 03E1 0467 03EC 0391 0003
```

Using the **ToUnicode** mapping of the font used here, these glyphs correspond with the following Unicode characters:

```
0003 0020 Space
03E1 0645 Meem  م
0467 0631 Reh   ر 
03EC 0647 Heh   ه
0391 0628 Beh   ب
0003 0020 Space
```

So, this indeed seems to be a 4-letter word.

This furthermore matches the last characters of the first line of the text extracted by PDFBox:

```
0020 0628 0647 0631 0645 0020
```

At least in case of the word pointed out by the OP, therefore, the data extracted by PDFBox is exactly what the data in the PDF contents express. If the glyphs drawn according to the font program read differently, the PDF information is inconsistent.

**PS:** In a comment the OP asked for

> ToUnicode Mapping for this font

It is this:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
26 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<< /Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
2 beginbfchar
<0003> <0020>
<0005> <0022>
endbfchar
2 beginbfrange
<000B> <000D> [<0029> <0028> <002A>]
<0010> <0012> <002D>
endbfrange
4 beginbfchar
<001D> <003A>
<003E> <005D>
<0040> <005B>
<00B1> <2013>
endbfchar
5 beginbfrange
<02EC> <02F4> [<060C> <0020> <061F> <0621> <0640> <064B> <0020> <0020> <0020>]
<02F5> <02F6> <064F>
<02F7> <02F8> [<0020> <0652>]
<0348> <0349> [<0020> <0647>]
<034A> <034B> <0651064F>
endbfrange
1 beginbfchar
<037F> <0631>
endbfchar
4 beginbfrange
<0381> <0385> [<0622> <062E> <0623> <0647> <0624>]
<0387> <038B> [<0625> <0645> <0020> <0626> <0626>]
<038D> <038D> [<0627>]
<038E> <038F> <0627>
endbfrange
1 beginbfchar
<0391> <0628>
endbfchar
2 beginbfrange
<0393> <0393> [<0629>]
<0394> <0395> <0629>
endbfrange
3 beginbfchar
<0397> <062A>
<0399> <062B>
<039B> <062B>
endbfchar
3 beginbfrange
<039D> <039F> [<062C> <062C> <062C>]
<03A1> <03A3> [<062D> <062D> <062D>]
<03A6> <03A7> [<062E> <062E>]
endbfrange
14 beginbfchar
<03A9> <062F>
<03AB> <0630>
<03AD> <0631>
<03AF> <0632>
<03B1> <0633>
<03B3> <0633>
<03B5> <0634>
<03B7> <0634>
<03B9> <0635>
<03BB> <0635>
<03BD> <0636>
<03BF> <0636>
<03C1> <0637>
<03C5> <0638>
endbfchar
5 beginbfrange
<03C9> <03D1> [<0639> <0639> <0639> <0639> <0020> <0629> <063A> <063A> <0641>]
<03D3> <03D3> [<0641>]
<03D4> <03D5> <0641>
<03D7> <03D7> [<0642>]
<03D8> <03D9> <0642>
endbfrange
2 beginbfchar
<03DB> <0643>
<03DD> <0644>
endbfchar
2 beginbfrange
<03DF> <03DF> [<0644>]
<03E0> <03E1> <0644>
endbfrange
3 beginbfchar
<03E3> <0645>
<03E5> <0646>
<03E7> <0646>
endbfchar
4 beginbfrange
<03E9> <03EB> [<0647> <0647> <0647>]
<03EC> <03ED> <0647>
<03EF> <03F3> [<0649> <0649> <0020> <0020> <064A>]
<03F5> <03FC> [<06440622> <0626> <06440623> <06440623> <06440625> <06440625> <06440627> <06440627>]
endbfrange
3 beginbfchar
<0467> <0631>
<0B09> <0650>
<0BCC> <0627064406440651064E>
endbfchar
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
```

Comment: First i thank you for your excellent and right analysis for this problem,after this analysis i would ask about:
why this letter(0467 0631 Reh  ر ) is exist in the stream?
and why pdf reader ignore it when displaying and pdfbox not ignore it?

Comment: If you view your PDF in Adobe reader and step through the word with the cursor, you'll see that there also are four steps. Looking at the sections of the word given by those steps, the Reh seems to be represented by a mere horizontal line.

Comment: You are right, can you get me the all ToUnicode Mapping for this font?
I need to see the unicode for this letter is different from the unicode for the main letter before mapping or not.

Comment: Please mkl do you know how to get character unicode before mapping using PDFBOX?

Comment: *character unicode before mapping* - before mapping it is not (necessarily) unicode. So I assume you mean the character code here. `PDFStreamEngine.processEncodedText` maps the character code to Unicode and calls `processTextPosition` with both values in the `TextPosition` parameter. The latter method is overridden in `PDFTextStripper`. If you want to intervene, these are the methods to look for.

Comment: I need character unicode before mapping so that i can detect the additional letter!,Finally Mr mkl from your experience because this topic is urgent for us, how can I detect this additional letter so that I can remove it from output or replace it with a mere 
horizontal line?

Comment: You can extend `PDFTextStripper` and override one of the methods I mentioned there. I don't know, though, how you can detect additional letters because I don't know which letters are unwanted and which are not.

Comment: Ok,the first word from left in the line you mentioned above:           
بهرم
'ر': this letter is the unwanted letter(second letter from left).

Comment: To program something like that you will need a criterion, not an example. By which criterion can a program recognize an unwanted letter?